# Can't create custom Vue component in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

In my JSFiddle example, I'm trying to define a custom Vue component: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/402951/ .

Unfortunately, nothing is rendered. Why?

The code:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<blog-post title="hi again!"></blog-post>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('blog-post', {
    props: ['title'],
    template: '<h3>{{ title }}</h3>'
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to create a Vue. Wrap the `<blogpost>` component into a div and create a Vue using that div as the template.

Like so

## HTML:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app"> 
    <blog-post title="hi again!"></blog-post>
</div>
```

## JS

```
Vue.component('blog-post', {
    props: ['title'],
    template: '<h3>{{ title }}</h3>'
})

// create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Look at the documentation [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/402986/)

Answer (score 1):

My friend I recommend you another option, that I preferred. Please use, if you want, sandbox where you can add or modify components much much easier.

Here is the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/kxjmlrjw05).